# Difference between Symfony/Doctrine commands "make:migration" and "doctrine:migrations:diff"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a differences between the Symfony console command `make:migration` and `doctrine:migrations:diff`?

Comment: `make:migration` is not a Symfony standard edition command ! ! you mean Laravel??

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-creating-the-database-tables-schema It's in their docs...

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between these two commands.

`make:migration` is simply a Symfony provided wrapper for the Doctrine command.

You can run either to the exact same effect. But the symfony one requires that you have the [Symfony Maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html), which otherwise it not required.

Answer (score 0):

`make:migration` will create empty file for you so you can write your custom migration

`doctrine:migrations:diff` will compare your current database schema with entities mappings and if there is difference then it will create migration so you can update you database schema to reflect your entities mappings

Comment: This is wrong. `make:migration` actually runs `doctrine:migrations:diff`. To create an empty migration you have to use `doctrine:migrations:generate`.